# hover effect on different classes in css

Tags: html, css, hover

i want have a hover effect for all elements in the follow html class

**HTML**

```css
.wrapper:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <i class="fa fa-icon"> </i>
  <h4> Headertext </h4>
  <p> Some content text </p>
  <p> <a href="url"> text </a> </p>
</div>
```

The hover works on the text. The problem is, i can`t tell all elements like the icon or the header to take the hover effect at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can either target all child nodes with the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) and * selector

```
.wrapper:hover > * {
  color: white;
}
```

or target individual ones:

```
.wrapper:hover > p {
  color: white;
}
```

or the less strict [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) :

```
.wrapper:hover p {
  color: white;
}
```

Either way, to affect the descendants when hovering over a parent you must use the `:hover` selector on the parent and then select the descendants.

Answer (score 0):

You cascade them down like this:

```
.wrapper:hover i,
.wrapper:hover h4,
.wrapper:hover p,
.wrapper:hover p {
   // some css here
}
```

Incidentally, this is why preprocessors like SASS and LESS are useful as you can declare your blocks this way:

```
.wrapper {
  &:hover {
    i {
      // some css here
    }
    h4 {
      // some css here
    }
    p {
      // some css here
    }
  }
}
```

Meaning you only have to describe the hover state once and can then chain all kinds of crazy styles from it to the children.

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks a ton so far.

i works nearly perfectly. I have only one issue:

i have tryed this code:

```
.wrapper:hover i,
.wrapper:hover h4,
.wrapper:hover a,
.wrapper:hover p {
color: white
}
```

and it works.

But if try to this with the background color it doesnt work:

Code

```
.wrapper:hover i,
    .wrapper:hover h4,
    .wrapper:hover a,
    .wrapper:hover p {
    color: white
    }

.wrapper:hover {
background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      
        $(".wrapper").hover(function () {
            $(".wrapper").css("color", "white");
            $(".txt").css("color", "white");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <i class="fa fa-icon"> </i>
  <h4> Headertext </h4>
  <p> Some content text </p>
  <p> <a class="txt" href="url"> text </a> </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```